# How to add @ symbol to string in android?

Tags: java, android

I am working on android. In my project I am adding '|' symbol and '@' symbol to string but it is not adding @ symbol. I am not
getting where I went wrong. Please help me with this.

```
String str="";
str = str + "|" + id + "@" + id2 + "@" + id3;
```

When I print the string "str" it is displaying only id value but it is not printing id1 and id2.
Output:
|13

Comment: String str="";
    str = str + "|" + 5 + "@" + 7 + "@" + 10;
    System.out.print(str);
    
    output : |5@7@10

Comment: same string is giving output in my device

Comment: The given string concat should work just fine. I would suggest you to use StringBuilder when there is lot of string concatenation involved.

Comment: can you post the complete code ? or the values of the variables.

Comment: It should always print correctly :S

Comment: Check you file encodings sometimes eclipse mess with the system encoding. All files encoding must be in "UTF-8".

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<string name="strings">\@Strings</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

i have check it like

```
String id = "A";
String id2 = "B";
String id3 = "C";

        String str="";
        str = str + "|" + id + "@" + id2 + "@" + id3;
```

and Output Like

```
|A@B@C
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this,

```
TextView tvAt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvAtExample);
String id1 = "A";
String id2 = "B"; 
String id3 = "C";
tvAt.setText(id1 + "|"+ id2 + "@" + id3);
```

Its working, It produces the output

A|B@C